# PostgreSQL - query JSON and replace JSON values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In Postgres DB one of the columns has this JSON data posted below.

When I do 'Select' query for that column - I want to replace JSON values of 'lib-One-5dc422e9f21531f9dbc16fd0' and 'lib-Six-5dc422e9f21531f9dbc16fd0' with just lib-One- and lib-Six- etc.

Am new to postgres and have been trying to figure this out for a while.

Basically replace any `lib-*-[0-9]` values with just `lib-*-`

```
{
   "data":{
      "Library":{
         "Checkout":{
            "invoiceId":"12dfdf454546",
            "checkoutDetail":{
               "invoiceTransactionId":"5ab422e9f21531f9dbc16fd6",
               "invoicePaymentDetail":{
                  "objectId":"lib-One-5dc422e9f21531f9dbc16fd0",
                  "checkoutPeriods":[
                     {
                        "startDate":"2017-04-14T19:00:00.000",
                        "endDate":"2017-05-19T19:00:00.000"
                     }
                  ],
                  "invoice":{
                     "objectId":"lib-Six-5dc422e9f21531f9dbc16fd0",
                     "checkObject":true
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eb7958cf3076e1317c934c14efb7eb0a)

I would solve it with RegEx function on the string:

```
SELECT
      regexp_replace('<your data>'::text, '"(lib-.*?-)(.*?)"', '"\1"', 'g')::json as a
```

1. Cast JSON object into string
2. Replace the relevant part: The parts can be found with the second parameter which gives out two groups per match. The replace string is only the first one.
3. Recast the result back into JSON

Comment: thanks @S-Man `SELECT
      regexp_replace('<your data>'::text, '"(lib-.*?-)(.*?)"', '"\1"', 'g')::json` Over there do I have to post the whole JSON in <your data>? It's a very long JSON. Is there a way I can just put the column name?

Comment: yes. column name works as well `SELECT regexp_replace(my_column::text, ...)`